# CSS not loading in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

It looks as though the css is not loading on secure pages. In the checkout the CSS is not loaded (fonts are changing). We are using cdn and I tried changing the media url for secure pages to the cdn url but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the view source of secure pages.change the http to https of css link of files.

Comment: In page.xml:                                                                                                                 <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>

Comment: I tried adding https: after <href> but no change.

Comment: Send me the website Url.

Comment: Sorry, this was a simple fix. The link was not in the xml file. It was in System > Configuration > Design > Head            -   and after the href I deleted the "http:" and now it works.